# jQuery Scroll Path?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a simple scroll path using this plugin "http://joelb.me/scrollpath/" and all I want to do is make a simple line, without rotations, arcs etc only I cant seem to understand how this works, nor find a tutorial on the plugin!?

I want a path like...

```
                __________________
 ______________|
```

I've written the following with no luck...

Can anyvbody see what im doing wrong?

```
.moveTo(400, 50, {name: "one"})
  .lineTo(400, 50, {name: "two"})
  .lineTo(400, 50, {name: "three"})
  .lineTo(400, 50, {name: "four"})
  .lineTo(400, 50, {name: "five"})
  .lineTo(400, 50, {name: "six"})
```

Comment: They are all on the same point? I don't know scrollpath, but I imagine you should change the position somehow if you want something to move around. Have you tried `lineTo(600, 50, {name: "two"})` and `lineTo(600, 100, {name: "three"})`. I really think you have to try different numbers

Comment: I've tried different numbers etc @FrancescoMM, each div is absolutely positioned

Comment: Ok, there may be other reasons for it not to work, also. But your path at the moment is all on a single point. You are telling it to move from (400, 50) -> to (400, 50) -> to (400, 50) etc.. You have to go from (400, 50) -> to (600, 50) -> to (600, 100) etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to use the `lineTo` thinking arguments are relative values (i.e. 'move to `400;50`'), but those are absolute, so your example moves to `400;50` and stays there.

Try something like this:

```
path
  .moveTo(50,100,{name: 'one'})
  .lineTo(400,100,{name: 'two'})
  .lineTo(400,50,{name: 'three'})
  .lineTo(800,50,{name: 'four'});
```

Additionally, when you init the plugin, pass `drawPath: true` as option, so you'll see how the path is implemented:

```
$(".your-container-element").scrollPath({
  drawPath: true,
});
```

---

you can find (some) documentation here: https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath

Comment: For me, drawPath: true doesn't print anything. Any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

What scrollpath does is bring the given (x,y) co-ordinates to the center of the screen.

For example

```
.moveTo(50,100,{name='a'})
```

will move (50,100) to the center of the screen.

So to use it you will have to use absolute positioning like so:

eg. div 1 =(50,100)
    div 2= (100,100)
    div 3= (150,100)

To handle this you have to

```
.moveTo(50,100,{name: 'div1'});
.moveTo(100,100,{name: 'div2'});
.moveTo(150,100,{name: 'div3'});
```

Remember that (50,100) is now the center, so if you place your div exactly (50,100) it will occupy space to the right bottom corner.

Instead center the entire div around (50,100)